# How to list the GCE subnetworks using the googleapiclient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I'm running `gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable` to get the list of Google Compute Engine subnetworks permitted for use, but I would like to do the same in googleapiclient, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compute Engine REST API method [subnetworks.listUsable](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/listUsable) returns pretty much the same as the `gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable` command (which I reckon could be just the equivalent). There is an example in Node.JS there too and you can filter the results to your liking. All you need to provide is the **project ID** when doing the request.

Comment: thank you very much for the pointer, it is working for me now.

Comment: @lotustub Thanks for the heads up. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful for broader visibility, and for the benefit of the community.